# Error con insertar objeto

Tags: javascript

quiero insertar en un arreglo objetos pero no funciona

```
$(this).find("input").each(function (index) {
                    console.log('INDEX', index);
                    arreglo.push({index: $(this).val()});
                });
```

`arreglo.push({index:` en esta parte index no es reconocido, porque?

Comment: que error te marca en la consola? o cuál es el problema exactamente?

Comment: prueba arreglo.push(new Array({index:$(this).val()})); Saludos :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está mal lo que venías haciendo, en vez de intentar ponerle el nombre al index en el objeto `{index: $(this).val()}` sólo deberías pasarle el valor del input.

```
// inicializo el array
var arreglo = [];

$(this).find("input").each(function (index) {
    // agrego al array el valor del input
    arreglo[index] = $(this).val();
});

console.log(arreglo);

// accedo a un valor del array
console.log(arreglo[1]);
```

Comment: pero quiero esta estructura {index: data}

Comment: digamos que index es 4 seria {4:data}

Comment: Ahí hice una modificación para que lo puedas generar dinámicamente.